# Split a string using one of two delimiters but retain delimiter

Tags: c#, regex, split

Using regex (or some other method), how would I split this text at the 5050's or 1010's

```
505079000012345    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL
505079000012346    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL
101014003412    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL
505079000012347    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL
101014003413    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL
```

So that the resulting strings are (note that I want to retain the delimiter strings at the begining of each string group):

```
505079000012345    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL

505079000012346    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL

101014003412    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL

505079000012347    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL

101014003413    ORE
10201 00
1030CA
1030AL
```

Comment: So `50501010` are two groups or only  if they are separated by spaces like in `5050 1010`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this pattern with `mg` option

```
^(?=5050|1010)
```

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/65)

or
`\R(?=5050|1010)` and replace w/ `\r\n\r\n`
[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/66)

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all matches with :

```
/((?:5050|1010)(?:(?!5050|1010).)*)/gs
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/rO4gU7/1) (Look at the Match information on the right panel)

The result is an array with each match

Hope it helps.